# Trying to construct a method that extract from an attack tree the possible paths

Tags: python, parsing, tree

I am trying to write a code that is able to extract all the possible paths from a dictionary representing an attack tree. I currently have something that works for one specific attack tree but fails with others.

```
children_dict = {
    'RobBank': ['OpenVault', 'BlowUp', ''],
    'OpenVault': ['LearnCombo', 'GetToVault', 'AND'],
    'BlowUp': ['GetToVault', ''],
    'LearnCombo': ['FindCode1', 'FindCode2', 'FindCode3', '2:3']}

import itertools

# Define a function named "extract_paths" that takes two arguments: a dictionary "children_dict" and a current node "node"
def extract_paths(children_dict, node):
    paths = []
    if node in children_dict:
        relations = children_dict[node]
        if relations[-1] == '':
            for child in relations[:-1]:
                child_paths = extract_paths(children_dict, child)
                for child_path in child_paths:
                    #print(type(child_path), child_path)
                    if len(child_path) == 1 and isinstance(child_path[0], list):
                        child_path = child_path[0]
                        print('QUA')
                    else:
                        child_path = child_path
                    #print(child_path, 'child_path')
                    
                    child_path.insert(0, node)
                    #print(child_path, 'child_path dopo')
                    paths.append(child_path)
        elif relations[-1] == 'AND' or relations[-1] == 'OAND':
            combined_path = [node]
            for child in relations[:-1]:
                child_paths = extract_paths(children_dict, child)
                if len(child_paths) == 1:
                    #print(len(child_paths), child_paths, 'len e child_paths')
                    if len(combined_path) > 1:
                        combined_path = [ child + child_paths[0] for child in combined_path]
                    #combined_path.extend(child_paths[0])
                else:
                    combined_path = [combined_path + child for child in child_paths]
                    #combined_path.append(child_paths)
            paths.extend(combined_path)
        elif relations[-1] == '2:3':
            items = relations[:-1]
            combinations = list(itertools.combinations(items, 2))
            for comb in combinations:
                paths.append([node] + list(comb))
        else:
            #print('here1' , [node] + relations[:-1])
            paths.append([node] + relations[:-1])
    else:
        paths.append([node])
    return paths
def main(children_dict):
    root = next(iter(children_dict))
    paths = extract_paths(children_dict, root)
    return paths

# Call the "main" function to generate and print the paths
paths = main(children_dict)
for path in paths:
    print(path)

#output:
#['RobBank', 'OpenVault', 'LearnCombo', 'FindCode1', 'FindCode2', 'GetToVault']
#['RobBank', 'OpenVault', 'LearnCombo', 'FindCode1', 'FindCode3', 'GetToVault']
#['RobBank', 'OpenVault', 'LearnCombo', 'FindCode2', 'FindCode3', 'GetToVault']
#['RobBank', 'BlowUp', 'GetToVault']
```

```
#It doesn't work with:
children_dict = {'BurgleHouse': ['EnterHouse', ''],
'EnterHouse': ['WalkUpToHouse', 'PenetrateHouse1', 'AND'],
'PenetrateHouse1': ['OpenPassageDoor1', 'EnterViaWindow', 'GarageAttack', ''],
'OpenPassageDoor1': ['BreakDownDoor', ''],
'EnterViaWindow': ['BreakGlass', ''],
 'GarageAttack': ['EnterGarage', 'PenetrateHouse2', 'AND'],
 'EnterGarage': ['OpenCarDoor', ''],
 'OpenCarDoor': ['SendDoorOpenerCode', ''],
 'SendDoorOpenerCode': ['StealOpenerFromCar', ''],
 'PenetrateHouse2': ['OpenPassageDoor2', ''],
'OpenPassageDoor2': ['BreakDownPassageDoor', '']}
```

Empty strings ('') represent an OR relation, while '2:3' represents a 2-out-of-3 relation.

Please let me know if you can help with this. I need something that could work with other attack trees. I have attempted to transform the dictionary into an XML format to use an official parser for path extraction, but I was unable to finalize a solution that works for all my attack trees.